# Plotting device with RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have issue with plotting `lines` over my existing plot in `.Rmd` in RStudio. I ran the code within the code chunk in `.Rmd` (⌘ + return) and the `plot` gives me a graph within the `.Rmd` (new feature of RStudio v1.0), however when I ran the second code `lines`, an error shows up.

```
plot(density(with$glucose), 
     ylim = c(0.00, 0.02),
     xlab = "Glucose Level",
     main = "Figure",
     lwd = 2)
lines(density(without$glucose), 
      col = "red",
      lwd = 2)
Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

On the other hand, if I copy and paste the codes into the console, I could get the plot I want, in the plot viewer within RStudio. 
[image]

In addition, when I ran some other codes within the `.Rmd` (⌘ + return), my plots in the plot viewer in RStudio disappear. This means I have to do copy-paste into the console instead of using the (⌘ + return) shortcut.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem, but you can solve it very easy: Press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to run the complete chunk, then everything works fine and you don't have to copy-and-paste all thing to the console.
So do all your plots in one chunk and run this chunk. This will produce you the plot within the RMD file (as you mentioned: new feature of RStudio 1.0)

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. Though I would rather have the plots appear in RStudio plot viewer for better view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a fan of the inline output / notebook mode for R Markdown documents, you can also disable it within the Global Options dialog -- try disabling the option:

- `Show output inline for all R Markdown document`

[image: R Markdown options]